# Struggling to understand Myhill-Nerode

Tags: regular-language, finite-automata, pumping-lemma

I think I know the pumping lemma and was told that Myhill-Nerode is a very elegant way to show that something is regular or not regular. But I am having a lot of trouble with it. Take this for example:

[image: L] = {0<sup>k</sup>, k = 2<sup>n</sup>, n >̲ 1}

My language is the repetition of 0 to a length that's a power of 2. I want to use the Myhill-Nerode to show that this is either regular or not regular. Is it possible?

I know how to set this up to resemble other Myhill-Nerode looking proofs but I don't understand the equivalence concept that much.

I could say that I have some [image: j] and [image: p] where [image: j] ≠ [image: p] and both are of the form 2<sup>h</sup> and [image: h e N], I then define [image: a], [image: b] and [image: c] so that:

[image: a] = 0<sup>j/2</sup>

[image: b] = 0<sup>p/2</sup>

[image: c] = 0<sup>j/2</sup>

Where [image: a][image: c] = 0<sup>j/2</sup>0<sup>j/2</sup> = 0<sup>j</sup> is in my language since [image: j] is of the form 2<sup>n</sup>, however  [image: b][image: c] = 0<sup>p/2</sup>0<sup>j/2</sup> is not guaranteed to be in my language for every p and j, since [image: j] ≠ [image: p]

Answer (score 2):

Given a languages L, two strings u, v 2 L are equivalent if for all
strings w belong to sigma *  we have that u.w belongs to L iff v.w belongs to L

consider the set of {0,0^2,0^4,0^8....}, in this case for some m and n 0^m and 0^n should be mapped to the same equivalence class or else there would be infinite equivalence classes making it non-regular by Myhill-Nerode theorem. However 0^m.0^m belong to L but 0^n.0^m would not ..Hence